# rxjs/ngrx multicast on .select

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, multicast, ngrx-store

In a `@Component`, should I always multicast the `.select(myCustomSelector)`?

e.g.

```
this.store.select(myCustomSelector).pipe(share());
```

Otherwise every time I do `async`, it will create a new subscription. Or is it fine because the selector is memoized?

I am wondering what's good practice.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. But yes, if you use multiple `async` pipes you're making multiple subscriptions.

Comment: But adding .share() to all of my observables seems like a code smell to me. Perhaps the performance increase isn't that substantial?

Comment: If your selectors just select something from the store, I think this isn't an issue at all. Even if you do some computations in your selectors, using the `createSelector` function will ensure the result is cached. But what you should do is to make sure to cancel the subscriptions when your component is destroyed (probably using `takeUntil`).

Comment: If you think adding share() is a code smell(but it is not), you can wrap your components via container (parent), subscribe once and pass the values to required components.

Answer (score 2):

No you should not use `share()` with your `.select()`

But it depends on what store implementation you are using.

in ngrx, ngxs, akita, the store is backed by an object and thus the observable returned from the select isn't going to trigger any side effects.

the store is then updated via a reducer, and then all the selects will get a new value, but since they are all working of this single object (state), it will not be a performance problem.

Comment: But what if in my view I have multiple async pipes? Surely this would impact performance because each async is a new subscription?

Comment: Using multiple async pipes for a given observable is an antipattern. it can be helped by subscribing to it once in ngOnInit and saving the result to a lokal variable, and then make sure to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy to not bleed a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do one `async` at the top level inside template and then reuse value?

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myItems$ | async as myItems">
<div *ngFor="let item of myItems">....</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of myItems">....</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of myItems">....</div>
</ng-container>
```